# How to create a new column which displays "1" for each new group of data?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dplyr

I am working on a really large dataset so I'm going to use an example dataset for simplicity. Here is the example dataset:

```r
df <- data.frame(Class = rep(c("Class A", "Class B"), each = 6),
                 Student = rep(c("Tom", "Ana", "Sam", "Ivy"), each = 3),
                 Subject = rep(c("Maths", "English", "Science"), times = 4),
                 Score = c(80, 75, 72, 86, 78, 80, 75, 77, 84, 81, 79, 88)
                 )

     Class Student Subject Score
1  Class A     Tom   Maths    80
2  Class A     Tom English    75
3  Class A     Tom Science    72
4  Class A     Ana   Maths    86
5  Class A     Ana English    78
6  Class A     Ana Science    80
7  Class B     Sam   Maths    75
8  Class B     Sam English    77
9  Class B     Sam Science    84
10 Class B     Ivy   Maths    81
11 Class B     Ivy English    79
12 Class B     Ivy Science    88
```

How can I add a new column called `new_block` using `mutate()` which displays `1` for each row where data for a different student appears, and `0` if not? Essentially, I would like this column to have `1` for rows 1, 4, 7, 10.

If possible, it would also be great to add another column called `last_record` which displays `1` for the last row of records for each student, and `0` if not - so `1` for rows 3, 6, 9, 12.

Also, is it possible to create these columns using `ifelse()`?

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but could you not just group by `Student` and get the first and last row? It depends on what you are using it for though.

Comment: In case you don't already know this, `case_when` used in the solutions below allows you to vectorize multiple `ifelse` statements. That is why you're not seeing `ifelse()` used explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Student) %>% mutate(new_block = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0), last_record = case_when(row_number() == n() ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   Student [4]
   Class   Student Subject Score new_block last_record
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Class A Tom     Maths      80         1           0
 2 Class A Tom     English    75         0           0
 3 Class A Tom     Science    72         0           1
 4 Class A Ana     Maths      86         1           0
 5 Class A Ana     English    78         0           0
 6 Class A Ana     Science    80         0           1
 7 Class B Sam     Maths      75         1           0
 8 Class B Sam     English    77         0           0
 9 Class B Sam     Science    84         0           1
10 Class B Ivy     Maths      81         1           0
11 Class B Ivy     English    79         0           0
12 Class B Ivy     Science    88         0           1
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Student) %>% 
  mutate(new_block = +(row_number() == 1),
         last_record = +(row_number() == n())) %>%
  ungroup()
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Class   Student Subject Score new_block last_record
   <fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <dbl>     <int>       <int>
 1 Class A Tom     Maths      80         1           0
 2 Class A Tom     English    75         0           0
 3 Class A Tom     Science    72         0           1
 4 Class A Ana     Maths      86         1           0
 5 Class A Ana     English    78         0           0
 6 Class A Ana     Science    80         0           1
 7 Class B Sam     Maths      75         1           0
 8 Class B Sam     English    77         0           0
 9 Class B Sam     Science    84         0           1
10 Class B Ivy     Maths      81         1           0
11 Class B Ivy     English    79         0           0
12 Class B Ivy     Science    88         0           1
```